# iterable long-object?

Tags: python, long-integer, iterable

This is a problem from euler-project. No.13

```
import math
#no.13

sum = []
number = 0

a = 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250463769376774900097126481248969700780504170182605387432498619952474105947423330951305812372661730962991942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250230675882075393461711719803104210475137780632466768926167069662363382013637841838368417873436172675728112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738442742289174325203219235894228767964876702721893184745144573600130643909116721685684458871160315327670386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951621764571418565606295021572231965867550793241933316490635246274190492910143244581382266334794475817892575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407582035653253593990084026335689488301894586282278288018119938482628201427819413994056758715117009439035398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586865155060062958648615320752733719591914205172558297169388870771546649911559348760353292171497005693854370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604532826541087568284431911906346940378552177792951453612327252500029607107508256381565671088525835072145876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045174237069058518606604482076212098132878607339694128114266041808683061932846081119106155694051268969251934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483624672216484350762017279180399446930047329563406911573244438690812579451408905770622942919710792820955037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126183363848253301546861961243487676812975343759465158038628759287849020152168555482871720121925776695478182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581167263201004368978425535399209318374414978068609844840309812907779179908821879532736447567559084803087086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332599594068957565367821070749269665376763262354472106979395067965269474259770973916669376304263398708541052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271653786073615010808570091499395125570281987460043753582903531743471732693212357815498262974255273730794953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275889028025717332296191766687138199318110487701902712526768027607800301367868099252546340106163286652636270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962240744869082311749777923654662572469233228109171419143028819710328859780666976089293863828502533340334413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470230530811728164304876237919698424872550366387845831148769693215490281042402013833512446218144177347063783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533677201869716985443124195724099139590089523100588229554825530026352078153229679624948164195386821877476085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236377742425354112916842768655389262050249103265729672370191327572567528565324825826546309220705859652229798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501184957014548792889848568277260777137214037988797153829820378303147352772158034814451349137322665138134829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539409579530664052326325380441000596549391598795936352974615218550237130764225512118369380358038858490341698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922624679571944012690438771072750481023908955235974572318970677254791506150550495392297953090112996751986188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672113067397083047244838165338735023408456470580773088295917476714036319800818712901187549131054712658197623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500428462801835170705278318394258821455212272512503275512160354698120058176216521282765275169129689778932238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886755061649651847751807381688378610915273579297013376217784275219262340194239963916804498399317331273132924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504995186714302352196288948901024233251169136196266227326746080059154747183079839286853520694694454072476841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818971426179103425986472045168939894221798260880768528778364618279934631376775430780936333301898264209010848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786713296124747824645386369930090493103636197638780396218407357239979422340623539380833965132740801111666627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411606618262936828367647447792391803351109890697907148578694408955299065364044742557608365997664579509666024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297649139826800329731560371200413779037855660850892521673093931987275027546890690370753941304265231501194809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791786391670211874924319957006419179697775990283006991536871371193661495281130587638027841075444973307840789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353448899115014406480203690680639606723221932041495354150312888033953605329934036800697771065056663195481234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280826165707739483275922328459417065250945123252306082291880205877731971983945018088807242966198081119777158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617721078384350691861554356628840622574736922845095162084960398013400172393067166682355524525280460972253503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690

s = str(a)

for f in range(100):
    for i in range(50):
        sum.append(s[i+f*100])
    a = int(''.join(str(i) for i in a))
    number += a
print number
```

I get this error message.

```
...
    a = int(''.join(str(i) for i in a))
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

My long object contains 5000 numbers. How could I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I thought it would be better to reshape the number. But it doesn't work yet.

```
import math
import numpy
#euler-project no.13

#next line: a not visible because it contains 5000 numbers!!!
a = 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250463769376774900097126481248969700780504170182605387432498619952474105947423330951305812372661730962991942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250230675882075393461711719803104210475137780632466768926167069662363382013637841838368417873436172675728112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738442742289174325203219235894228767964876702721893184745144573600130643909116721685684458871160315327670386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951621764571418565606295021572231965867550793241933316490635246274190492910143244581382266334794475817892575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407582035653253593990084026335689488301894586282278288018119938482628201427819413994056758715117009439035398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586865155060062958648615320752733719591914205172558297169388870771546649911559348760353292171497005693854370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604532826541087568284431911906346940378552177792951453612327252500029607107508256381565671088525835072145876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045174237069058518606604482076212098132878607339694128114266041808683061932846081119106155694051268969251934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483624672216484350762017279180399446930047329563406911573244438690812579451408905770622942919710792820955037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126183363848253301546861961243487676812975343759465158038628759287849020152168555482871720121925776695478182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581167263201004368978425535399209318374414978068609844840309812907779179908821879532736447567559084803087086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332599594068957565367821070749269665376763262354472106979395067965269474259770973916669376304263398708541052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271653786073615010808570091499395125570281987460043753582903531743471732693212357815498262974255273730794953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275889028025717332296191766687138199318110487701902712526768027607800301367868099252546340106163286652636270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962240744869082311749777923654662572469233228109171419143028819710328859780666976089293863828502533340334413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470230530811728164304876237919698424872550366387845831148769693215490281042402013833512446218144177347063783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533677201869716985443124195724099139590089523100588229554825530026352078153229679624948164195386821877476085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236377742425354112916842768655389262050249103265729672370191327572567528565324825826546309220705859652229798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501184957014548792889848568277260777137214037988797153829820378303147352772158034814451349137322665138134829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539409579530664052326325380441000596549391598795936352974615218550237130764225512118369380358038858490341698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922624679571944012690438771072750481023908955235974572318970677254791506150550495392297953090112996751986188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672113067397083047244838165338735023408456470580773088295917476714036319800818712901187549131054712658197623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500428462801835170705278318394258821455212272512503275512160354698120058176216521282765275169129689778932238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886755061649651847751807381688378610915273579297013376217784275219262340194239963916804498399317331273132924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504995186714302352196288948901024233251169136196266227326746080059154747183079839286853520694694454072476841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818971426179103425986472045168939894221798260880768528778364618279934631376775430780936333301898264209010848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786713296124747824645386369930090493103636197638780396218407357239979422340623539380833965132740801111666627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411606618262936828367647447792391803351109890697907148578694408955299065364044742557608365997664579509666024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297649139826800329731560371200413779037855660850892521673093931987275027546890690370753941304265231501194809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791786391670211874924319957006419179697775990283006991536871371193661495281130587638027841075444973307840789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353448899115014406480203690680639606723221932041495354150312888033953605329934036800697771065056663195481234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280826165707739483275922328459417065250945123252306082291880205877731971983945018088807242966198081119777158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617721078384350691861554356628840622574736922845095162084960398013400172393067166682355524525280460972253503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690

b = numpy.arange(a).reshape(100,50)
print b
```

2.EDIT:

```
import math
#no.13

a = """3710728753390210279879799822083759024651013574025046376""".split() #contains much more numbers

b = [int(x) for x in a]     #b --> list
print b[1]
```

I got an error again.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But i dont know why. I think b is a normal list isn't it?

EDIT No. 3:

```
import math
#no.13
#Work out the first ten digits of the sum
#of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.
#a is the number

b = []
#next line: a = list("3710728753390210279879..................")
a = list("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250463769376774900097126481248969700780504170182605387432498619952474105947423330951305812372661730962991942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250230675882075393461711719803104210475137780632466768926167069662363382013637841838368417873436172675728112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738442742289174325203219235894228767964876702721893184745144573600130643909116721685684458871160315327670386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951621764571418565606295021572231965867550793241933316490635246274190492910143244581382266334794475817892575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407582035653253593990084026335689488301894586282278288018119938482628201427819413994056758715117009439035398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586865155060062958648615320752733719591914205172558297169388870771546649911559348760353292171497005693854370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604532826541087568284431911906346940378552177792951453612327252500029607107508256381565671088525835072145876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045174237069058518606604482076212098132878607339694128114266041808683061932846081119106155694051268969251934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483624672216484350762017279180399446930047329563406911573244438690812579451408905770622942919710792820955037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126183363848253301546861961243487676812975343759465158038628759287849020152168555482871720121925776695478182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581167263201004368978425535399209318374414978068609844840309812907779179908821879532736447567559084803087086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332599594068957565367821070749269665376763262354472106979395067965269474259770973916669376304263398708541052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271653786073615010808570091499395125570281987460043753582903531743471732693212357815498262974255273730794953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275889028025717332296191766687138199318110487701902712526768027607800301367868099252546340106163286652636270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962240744869082311749777923654662572469233228109171419143028819710328859780666976089293863828502533340334413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470230530811728164304876237919698424872550366387845831148769693215490281042402013833512446218144177347063783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533677201869716985443124195724099139590089523100588229554825530026352078153229679624948164195386821877476085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236377742425354112916842768655389262050249103265729672370191327572567528565324825826546309220705859652229798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501184957014548792889848568277260777137214037988797153829820378303147352772158034814451349137322665138134829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539409579530664052326325380441000596549391598795936352974615218550237130764225512118369380358038858490341698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922624679571944012690438771072750481023908955235974572318970677254791506150550495392297953090112996751986188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672113067397083047244838165338735023408456470580773088295917476714036319800818712901187549131054712658197623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500428462801835170705278318394258821455212272512503275512160354698120058176216521282765275169129689778932238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886755061649651847751807381688378610915273579297013376217784275219262340194239963916804498399317331273132924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504995186714302352196288948901024233251169136196266227326746080059154747183079839286853520694694454072476841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818971426179103425986472045168939894221798260880768528778364618279934631376775430780936333301898264209010848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786713296124747824645386369930090493103636197638780396218407357239979422340623539380833965132740801111666627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411606618262936828367647447792391803351109890697907148578694408955299065364044742557608365997664579509666024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297649139826800329731560371200413779037855660850892521673093931987275027546890690370753941304265231501194809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791786391670211874924319957006419179697775990283006991536871371193661495281130587638027841075444973307840789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353448899115014406480203690680639606723221932041495354150312888033953605329934036800697771065056663195481234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280826165707739483275922328459417065250945123252306082291880205877731971983945018088807242966198081119777158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617721078384350691861554356628840622574736922845095162084960398013400172393067166682355524525280460972253503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690")
sum = 0
#len(a) = 5000

for y in range(99):  #100 is correct but why
    for x in range(49): #50 numbers --> range(49)
        b.append(a[x+y*50])
    c = int(''.join(str(i) for i in b))
    sum += c
    b = []
    c = 0
    print y
print sum
```

I have a last question? Why is 100 correct and not 99?
And do you think my Editing-style is bad? Should I remove the rest? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=13　I want to solve this problem.

Comment: @kame: The answer you have accepted is probably not the answer that you want.

Comment: It was the answer I want, but after this a got a new problem. :/

Comment: You didn't try the above `numpy.arange` on your poor computer, did you?

Comment: In your latest edit, is the `split` at the end of your string literal necessary? You are basically getting a list with one string. if you need a list of all the digits, just do `list("371072....")`.

Comment: i try it with list now. It looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the overall goal of your program is but the error you are getting is because in the line:

```
a = int(''.join(str(i) for i in a))
```

You are trying to iterate over a `long` and in `Python` as the error message indicates a `long` is not an iterable you cannot process it one digit at a time directly. You can convert the long to a string and process that one character at a time. In your program you have already converted the number `a` to the sting `s` with the line: `s = str(a)` so you can fix your problem by changing the problematic line above with the code below:

```
a = int(''.join(str(i) for i in s))
```

Comment: Doesn't that last line just reconstruct the long value you had to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to solve [Project Euler #13](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=13).

Your variable `a` should be a list of integers, not one big long integer:

```
a = [
    37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250,
    46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538,
    74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629,
    ...
]
```

or to avoid typing the commas:

```
a = """37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
...
""".split()
a = [int(x) for x in a]
```

You might also find the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) builtin useful.

Comment: maybe I should shape it at first.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean 'shape it'?

Comment: numpy.arange(a).reshape(100,50) ----> ValueError: Maximum allowed size exceeded :(

Comment: Why are you using numpy to solve this? It's not needed. Can you post your code? I'm really not sure what you are doing. The code in your question doesn't mention numpy.

Comment: this was my last try. I wrote that i should reshape this big number into a 100-50-shape.

Comment: numpy.reshape http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html is for reshaping arrays. It doesn't work on longs.

Comment: Copy the values into source code, put `[]` around it and append a comma at the end of each line (the editor can hopefully do it).

Comment: But this takes too much time. There should be an other way.

Comment: Maybe i should change the long to an array. After this I will use reshape.

Comment: Using numpy is not a good way to do this. You could use a triple-quote string literal and then split it. I'll update my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code snippet is really close. A smaller version of what you're doing is:

```
a = """12345""".split()
b = [int(x) for x in a]
```

b now equals ['12345'], a list with a single string in it. That's why b[1] raises an error, because it's asking for the second element in a one-element list. Split defaults to using whitespace as the delimiter, so with no whitespace the string is unchanged. Here's the correct code, though I've no comments on its speed for your purposes:

```
a = """12345"""
b = [int(x) for x in a]
```

or, to jump right into using a loop construct:

```
a = """12345"""
for each in a:
    num = int(each)
    ... sum the new number ...
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the OP knows, but maybe others don't, the problem statement is:  "work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers," followed naturally by 100 50-digit integers.

The problem is designed to make it difficult to simply add the numbers together.

Now, there is some ambiguity about the word "first", but if I recall I believe they are talking about the highest-value digits of the sum.

@[kame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237934/kame), a hint:  how would you do this by hand?  emulate that in Python.

edit:

if you save the numbers as text in 'data.txt', this will give them to you in the form needed to continue:

```
FH = open('data.txt')
data = FH.read()
FH.close()
L = data.strip().split('\n')
L = [list(e.strip()) for e in L]
L2 = list()
for e in L:
    L2.append([int(c) for c in e])    
for e in L2:  print e
```

Comment: my bad:  Python's support for huge numbers makes this approach unnecessary
>>> 2**151377 + 2**245788
363558462...

Comment: AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'strip'